# Why div::before shows on top of the children element?

Tags: css

This doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't ::before get rendered before the span? It works if I add position:relative to the child element.

This could have something to do with the stacking context, but I'm not sure how exactly.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers

The span in this case falls in #3 because it's non-positioned and ::before #6 because it's a positioned descendant?

```css
div { position:relative; }

div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* Adding this works: */
/* span { position: relative; } */
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `position:absolute` so it is being placed exactly where you tell it, i.e. in the top left corner.

Comment: It does have something to do with stacking context, for example, if you declare any `z-index` value other than `auto`, like `-1`, you will create a stacking context, and the `:pseudo-element` will appear below the sibling `span` element. Without a `z-index` value declared, the absolutely positioned element will always appear above any "un-positioned" elements or `static` elements (*e.g: `position: static`*) - which is generally the default positioning of any element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an item doesn't have `position` set, then it's set pretty low in the layout. If you position any element as `absolute` you should give some `position` to all the sibling elements. In this example `::before` and `span` are siblings, and since `::before` has position and `span` doesn't `::before` is more "important"

Comment: I wish all answers are explained to me like that. So simple to understand without technical jargons.

I've been doing CSS for a while and I think this is the first time (that I can remember of) that I have to explicitly declare position:relative when using ::before.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified that position is `absolute` it makes content to be in another flow level. You can try to specify `z-index`, however even that not always works. For example if you have some element with `absolute/relative` positioning it will be over `static` with any number of z-index.

Answer (score 1):

You can set z-index to -1 nowadays to make it appear below all children.

Comment: Source: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_z-index_negative_values

Answer (score 0):

How `:pseudo` CSS class works is the element will be added **before and within** the element.

**like so:**

```
<div>
  :before
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

I'm not very what you need to achieve but to explain your doubt, the reason you are producing the current outcome after adding `position:relative` to your div is because `:before` is set with `position:absolute`. By doing so **it will pull the :before element out of the current html hierarchy** and position itself relative to the nearest element where you set `div { position:relative; }`.

Since the before is being pulled out of the hierarchy the `<span>` will fill up the empty space available (aka overlapped by :before).